# open vim in alternate directory in windows

Tags: vim

using vim + NERDTree in windows is a bit of a pain for me because each time I start vim and toggle NERDTree, NERDTree takes a long time caching my whole /Windows/system32 directory.

In order to avoid that, how can I create a shortcut to open vim in say C:\users\me\vim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add somewhere in your .vimrc.

`cd C:\users\me\vim`

It will change the working directory of your Vim instance.

According to `:help starting.txt`.vimrc is loaded before plugins.